# References with PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE cars_info.cars
(
    id SERIAL,
    owner_id INTEGER,
    brand VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    model VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    color VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    register_number VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    created DATE NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY(id, brand, model, color, register_number, created),
  
    CONSTRAINT fk_owner_id
        FOREIGN KEY(owner_id)
            REFERENCES persons_info.persons(id)
);
```

But when I tried create another table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE cars_info.violations
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    car_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    message VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    active BOOLEAN NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT fk_car_id
        FOREIGN KEY(car_id)
            REFERENCES cars_info.cars(id)
);
```

I get an error about that

> Target external table "cars" does not have a unique constraint corresponding to the given keys

How can I fix that? I'm a beginner in SQL and don't know how to go about googling that

Comment: The primary key of your cars table consists of all the columns in the table - so any foreign key must use all those column. However, including all columns in the primary key does not make any sense to begin with.

Comment: The way you have set the primary key on the cars table means that I can come in tomorrow and add the same id, owner, car registration a second time, because create date is part of the key.  I'm sure you don't want that.  What makes a record unique? In this case, the id is already unique (as a serial number) and is your sole primary key.  If you need to ensure the same car is not entered twice, you can add some constraints.  For example, car registrations should be unique, so you can add a unique index to cars on registration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your primary key definition for `cars`

```
PRIMARY KEY(id, brand, model, color, register_number, created)
```

makes no sense: The `id` column, being `serial`, is itself unique and it alone should be the primary key.

Delete your primary key definition and change the id column definition to:

```
id serial not null primary key
```

---

Unrelated, but best practice is to name table in the singular; name your tables `car` and `violation` rather than `cars` and `violations`

Comment: kk, thanks for the help, i'll rename my tables for best practice :)

Comment: Best practice on singular or plural names is an opinion and subject to *local standards*. The important thing is to be consistent and always use singular names or always use plural.

Comment: @Belayer while it's true that everything is an opinion, a table definition is primarily the definition of a *row* - the column definitions. Sure there are other aspects you can also define, but the minimum required and therefore the fundamentals are the columns for each **single** row. When selecting data from the table you read it 1 row at a time, so you're only ever dealing with **one** customer; never "customers". Then there's the grammar aspect: `customer.name` reads naturally but `customers.name` does not. Note that "customer's name" being correct is a vote for singular naming convention.